# Flume and sqoop limitation

Tags: performance, sqoop, flume

I have a terabyte of data files on different machines i want to collect it on centralized machine for some processing is it advisable to use flume ?

Same amount of data is there in RDBMS which i would like to put in hdfs is it advisable to use sqoop to trasffer terabyte of data? if not what will be alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Sqoop to transfer few terabytes from RDBMS to HDFS is a great idea, highly recommended. This is Sqoop's intended use case and it does do reliably.

Flume is mostly intended for streaming data, so if the files all have events, and you get new files frequently, then Flume with Spooling Directory source can work.

Otherwise, "HDFS -put" is a good way to copy files to HDFS.

Comment: can i not trasfer static files using flume? size is in terabytes

Comment: then what about the log files which are already present and i need to move them to centralized storage

Comment: hdfs -put is a great way to move log files.